# VueJS handle multiple promise on page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, loading

I've search through lot of issues and still did not find how to solve it, so you're my last chance...

I have a Vue Component who needs to load data from an API on creation and then display these datas in the component. I already did this before without any issues but for this one i'm making, it doesn't work...

```js
<template>
    <thead v-if="loaded">
    <tr>
        <th v-for="label in labels">
            {{label}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</template>

<script>
    import Schema from '../../api/schema'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                labels: [],
                loaded: false
            }
        },
        props: {
            fields: Array
        },
        methods: {
            getFieldsLabels: function () {
                return Promise.all(
                    this.fields
                        .map((field) => Schema().getField(field)
                            .then(response => response.getLabel())
                        )
                )
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getFieldsLabels().then(
                response => {
                    this.loaded = true;
                    this.labels = response
                }
            )
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have multiple promises that I pass in `Promise.all` but when I press F5 on my browser, the page remains blank. But when it reloads with HMR it works...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

i think because you try to use `then` of response of another `then`

Try that

```
        getFieldsLabels: function () {
            return Promise.all(
                this.fields
                    .map((field) => Schema().getField(field))
            )
        }
```

You need to add `getLabel` to the the `mounted` function

```
        this.getFieldsLabels().then(
            response => {
                this.loaded = true;
                this.labels = response.getLabel()
            }
        )
```

Comment: I've already tried this, still the same issue. It works with HMR, but not with a full page reload (F5)

Comment: what you mean by HMR ?

Comment: Hot Module Replacement